# Push arrays to one array, then cycle through new array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, frequency

I need to cycle through several arrays to find the out how often a particular value shows up.

I can pass the values to one new array, and this works, however when I try to loop through it it doesn't seem to work.

As this is for class, I cannot use jQuery - solely logic!!

```
var mon = ["Ez, Caro"];
var tue = ["Ez, Matt, Pablo"];
var wed = ["Marta"];
var thur = ["Ez, Matt"];
var freq = 0;
var arr = [];

var input = prompt ("Search a name");

arr.push(mon, tue, wed, thur);

for (var i = 0; i<arr.length; i++){
  if (arr[i] == input){

    freq = freq + 1;
  }

}
document.write("It appears " + freq + " time(s)")
```

Comment: Each one of your arrays contain a single string... did you mean `var mon = ['Ez', 'Caro'];`... etc?

Comment: it seems you have a single item in each array (mon, tue, wed, thur) is that right or is a typo?

Comment: @xavvvier chazsolo yes you're right. Felt so dumb for this so fixed it but still saying that each value appears 0 times

Comment: when you do `arr.push(mon, tue, wed, thur)` you end up with `arr = [["Ez, Caro"], ["Ez, Matt, Pablo"], ["Marta"], ["Ez, Matt"]]` that's an array of arrays, and in the validation `if(arr[i] == input)` you are comparing arrays and strings (`[Ez, Caro] == 'Ez, Caro'`), that's why the `freq` variable does not change

Comment: @stesand may [edit] your question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that each array is supposed to have multiple strings instead of just one like in the question, you could do something like below with vanilla JavaScript. Check the comments for logic.

```js
var mon = ["Ez", "Caro"];
var tue = ["Ez", "Matt", "Pablo"];
var wed = ["Marta"];
var thur = ["Ez", "Matt"];

//combine your arrays for simplicity
var arr = mon.concat(tue).concat(wed).concat(thur);

//use an object as a map to keep track of count
var map = {};
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if (!map[arr[i]]) {
    map[arr[i]] = 1;
  } else {
    map[arr[i]] = map[arr[i]] + 1;
  }
}

//get the user input
var input = prompt("Search a name");

//store the count of requested input (case-sensitive)
var countOfRequested = map[input] ? map[input] : 0;

//display to the user
console.log(input + ' appears ' + countOfRequested + ' times.');
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem is, with `Array.push` you are creating an array of arrays instead of merging them, which is the desired result here. Check out `Array.concat`, or try ES6 `spread` syntax.

Answer (score 1):

You can combine all members of the arrays into one single array, and use [`.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to sum up the input you targeting.

To combine the values you can either use the [ES2015 `spread` syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator):

```
var combinedArray = [...mon, ...tue, ...wed, ...thur];
```

Or older version of javascript with [`.concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) (i use apply to not mutate the array):

```
var combinedArray = [].concat.apply([],[mon,tue,wed,thur]);
```

Here is a running example:

```js
var mon = ["Ez", "Caro"];
var tue = ["Ez", "Matt", "Pablo"];
var wed = ["Marta"];
var thur = ["Ez", "Matt"];
// ES6
var combinedArray = [...mon, ...tue, ...wed, ...thur];
// ES5
//var combinedArray = [].concat.apply([],[mon,tue,wed,thur]);

function countInput(input, arr) {
  var count = arr.reduce(function(sum, current) {
    if (current === input) {
      sum += 1;
    }
    return sum;
  }, 0);
  return count;
}

var input = 'Ez';
var count = countInput(input, combinedArray);
console.log("The count of " + input + ' - ',count);
```

Answer (score 0):

Close, but not quite. Push inserts the entire element inside the array. That includes the fact that each day of the week is an array.

```
arr = [["Ez, Caro"], ["Ez, Matt, Pablo"], ["Marta"], ["Ez, Matt"]]
```

You're looking for `concat`, or select the string itself in the array, by grabbing the element by its index number, which is `0`

```
arr.push(mon[0], tue[0], wed[0], thur[0]);
```

or

```
arr.concat(mon, tue, wed, thur)
```

As a side note, you don't have to write it as `freq = freq + 1;`. `freq += 1` is convention that everyone uses.

Comment: Cheers! Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

By using push function you are making array of arrays .. so you can use a nested loop to iterate through this 2d array .. so your code will be

```
        var mon = ["Ez", "Caro"];
        var tue = ["Ez", "Matt", "Pablo"];
        var wed = ["Marta"];
        var thur = ["Ez", "Matt"];
        var freq = 0;
        var arr = [];
        var input = prompt ("Search a name");
        arr.push(mon, tue, wed, thur);
        for (i = 0; i<arr.length; i++)
            for(j = 0; j < arr.length; j++)
                if (arr[i][j] == input)
                    freq++;
        document.write("It appears " + freq + " time(s)")
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

The following code should works. It's written is ES6, just let me know if you are not comfortable with that.

```
const mon = ["Ez", "Caro"];
const tue = ["Ez", "Matt", "Pablo"];
const wed = ["Marta"];
const thur = ["Ez", "Matt"];

const names = [...mon, ...tue, ...wed, ...thur]

const input = prompt ("Search a name");

const freq = names.filter(a => a===input).length

document.write("It appears " + freq + " time(s)")
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to look at is your arrays. Because of where you have your quotation marks, I don't think you're getting the expected values. For example, in `mon` I believe you're expecting 2 values: "Ez" and "Caro", however, the missing quotes means you only have one element in the array: "Ez, Caro". Change your arrays to look like this instead:

```
var mon = ["Ez", "Caro"];
var tue = ["Ez", "Matt", "Pablo"];
var wed = ["Marta"];
var thur = ["Ez", "Matt"];
var freq = 0;
```

Then, you can create `arr` like this:

```
var arr = [].concat(mon, tue, wed, thur);
```

This takes an empty array (`[]`) and concatinates the 4 arrays you're looking at. From here, the loop should work just fine. So, the whole thing:

```
var mon = ["Ez", "Caro"];
var tue = ["Ez", "Matt", "Pablo"];
var wed = ["Marta"];
var thur = ["Ez", "Matt"];
var freq = 0;
var arr = [].concat(mon, tue, wed, thur);

var input = prompt ("Search a name");

for (var i = 0; i<arr.length; i++){
  if (arr[i] == input){

    freq = freq + 1;
  }

}
document.write("It appears " + freq + " time(s)");
```

Answer (score 0):

May just use a nested loop:

```
 const days = [mon, tue, wed, thur];

 let freq = 0, input = "Ez";

 for(const day of days){
    for(const person of day){
        if(person === input) freq++;
    }
 }
```